# Manga about a woman who plays a game set in ancient China on her phone and, in the game, helps an abandoned prince

Tags: story-identification, manga

I need help identifying this manga. I read it over a year ago, and I just can't remember the name.

The main female character is a modern woman who is hospitalized, and while there, she has a random game app link show up on her phone. Thinking that she has nothing better to do, she downloads to play.

The game is set in ancient Chinese imperial court style. The game shows an abandoned prince, the main male character, who is bullied by either the empress or a high-ranking imperial consort; I can't remember which for sure. However, since it's a "game," she only sees a pixelated character. The game has functions that allow her to interact with this other world without realizing it is very much real. Slowly improving his life and environment as she plays. The game also has the dreaded pay-for-better items, but she's poor and can't afford to spend much of anything on what she sees as a game.

Does anyone know the name of this manga?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Was the artwork mostly black & white or full colour?